# Best console based text editor not only for programmers

Tags: vim, terminal, emacs, text-editors, console

I need console based text editor for writing both source codes and human readable texts such as emails.
I need it to be user friendly. It mean for me:

- You can use it the same way as the notepad or gedit.
- You can use mouse there.
- If you need your mother of girlfriend or somebody to edit your text they will know what to do, they will not realize it is a console and will have only a feeling it is something like a notepad.
- copy, paste, undo works as usual with usual key combinations (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, Ctrl-Z).
- shift and arrows works as usual. They select the text.

And when I return to the computer I want to use the text editor for programming. I expect:

- Syntax highliting
- auto indenting
- replacing spaces with tabs
- keyboard shortcuts for compiling
- possibility to configure it to use a debugger
- autocompletions for c#, java, c++ and other languages
- other things I expect from IDE's.

I was working and configuring vim for a few years. But It never fulfilled all of my expectations (but it almost did).

I thing I could get vim configured perfectly if I had few more weeks time for configurating it. Unfortunately I cannot afford to be configuring vim forever.

Is there other alternative? Hopefully some editor I once set up and it will works forever?
What do you use? I often hear people are using emacs. Is it worth learning?

Comment: I don't get why this question was closed. Did you try [ne](http://ne.dsi.unimi.it/), [joe](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/), [diakonos](http://diakonos.pist0s.ca/)? But you are asking for two mutually exclusive sets of features: such requirements *can only lead to compromise.*

Answer (score 1):

[Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/index.html) is based on Vim, but not for the hard-core users. As it’s just a set of vim scripts, it should work in the console, though I’ve never tried it.

Comment: Thanks for good tip. This editor is evidently capable of everything vim is able to do. It starts in insert mode... and knows the common keyboard shortcuts ... looks perfect

Comment: Unfortunately according to FAQ they don't support editing in console. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [GNU nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/) as it is simple and supports syntax highlighting.

<sup>Screenshot from [nano’s Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano):</sup>.
[image: Screenshot of GNU nano]